# What's the difference between "return View()" and "return PartialView()"

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I understand that partial views are used to render parts of a view. But I can't understand what's the difference between `return View()` and `return PartialView()` and when do you use each one.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Return `View()` - Renders an .aspx|.cshtml page

- Renders a normal .aspx page that can also contain Partial Views

Return `PartialView()` - Renders .ascx|.cshtml Control

- Renders a segment of HTML to the browser that can be requested through AJAX or Non-AJAX requests alike.

View() returns `ViewResult`
PartialView() returns `PartialViewResult`
both inherit from `ViewResultBase`

The difference is described by [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) below...

```
public class PartialViewResult : ViewResultBase
{
   // Methods
   protected override ViewEngineResult FindView(ControllerContext context)
   {
      ViewEngineResult result = base.ViewEngineCollection.FindPartialView(context, base.ViewName);
      if (result.View != null)
      {
         return result;
      }
      StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
      foreach (string str in result.SearchedLocations)
      {
         builder.AppendLine();
         builder.Append(str);
      }
      throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, MvcResources.Common_PartialViewNotFound, new object[] { base.ViewName, builder }));
   }
}


public class ViewResult : ViewResultBase
{
   // Fields
   private string _masterName;

   // Methods
   protected override ViewEngineResult FindView(ControllerContext context)
   {
      ViewEngineResult result = base.ViewEngineCollection.FindView(context, base.ViewName, this.MasterName);
      if (result.View != null)
      {
         return result;
      }
      StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
      foreach (string str in result.SearchedLocations)
      {
         builder.AppendLine();
         builder.Append(str);
      }
      throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, MvcResources.Common_ViewNotFound, new object[] { base.ViewName, builder }));
   }

   // Properties
   public string MasterName
   {
      get
      {
         return (this._masterName ?? string.Empty);
      }
      set
      {
         this._masterName = value;
      }
   }
}
```

[image]

Comment: i'd downvote if i could, but ReturnView() vs View() has absolutely nothing to do with whether an ".aspx" or ".ascx" view is rendered.  CORRECTION -- it appears that it may indeed handle what view is fetched using convention (i.e.: controller renders view of same name).  regardless, you can feed both a .aspx and a .ascx view to PartialView() with no problems.

Comment: `View()` returns a `ViewResult` and PartialView() returns a `PartialViewResult`. Run Reflector on the two methods for yourself and see which one you should use when deciding what to render. `PartialViewResult` and `ViewResult` are two different classes that both inherit from `ViewResultBase`, which are intended for different purposes! PartialViews don't have MasterPages (Views can), are you really going to render "`somecontrol.ascx`" using `View()`...

Comment: @xandercoded all these answers and comments can be replaced by your `PartialViews don't have MasterPages`

Comment: could be great if someone could explain the reflector code differences in simple words

Answer (score 17):

return PartialView() returns HTML code fragment and it is used with ViewUserControls - ASCX files. The main advantage of using "return PartialView()" is when you don't want to render all the other HTML page stuff, like HTML, BODY, HEAD tags.

One of the most common uses by me is when I want to render just the user control based on whether the request to an action is AJAX call.

So I have a View called MyControl.aspx where I use RenderPartial HTML helper and I have a partial View named MyControl.ascx where I do the actual render.

I can switch between those two in my controller action like this:

```
if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    return PartialView("MyControl"); // this renders MyControl.ascx

return View(); // this render MyControl.aspx
```

Answer (score 2):

A controller action typically returns a PartialView when AJAX is used, and an update of the page region represented by the partial view is performed. The normal way to use partial views is simply to call `Html.RenderPartial` inside your main view.