# Extract Div from returned view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I an working on returning view from controller to jquery ,View is returned but i want to extract div from returned view.My Current code is like this

```
       public ActionResult DeleteItem(int pid)
                {
                 //my logic goes here
                    retutn View("SomeView",model);
                    }

                 Jquery


enter code here
          script type="text/javascript">
              $(document).ready(function () {

        $('.Remove').click(function () {
             var value = $(this).attr('id');
            $.ajax({
                cache:true,
                type: "POST",
                url: "@(Url.Action("DeleteItem", "ControllerName"))",
                data: "pid=" + value,
                success: function (data) {
                    $("body").html(data);

                },
                error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                    alert('Failed to subscribe.');

                }, 
                complete: function() {   } 
           });       
            return false;
                 });
                      });

        </script>
```

My current logic returns view and assign total view i.e html+body to body part of page ,which shows html part two times.Is there any way to retrieve div from the returned view and reload it.
thanx in advance

Comment: Nitin dada, lai complicated prashna aahe.

Comment: Bhava,Nahi kalala ka prashna,sangu ka parat,Mazya view madhye bharpur div tag ahet,mala tyatala innermost ghyayachay view madhun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
      script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function () {

    $('.Remove').click(function () {
         var value = $(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({
            cache:true,
            type: "POST",
            url: "@(Url.Action("DeleteItem", "ControllerName"))",
            data: "pid=" + value,
            success: function (data) {
                     var t=$(data).find('.divtoreplacewith');
                               $('.divtoreplace').replaceWith(d);
         //Wasted my 2 days for above two lines.But satisfied with solution,
          //Both div are same but '.divtoreplacewith' is having new data,And I have replaced div with that div that's all
            },
            error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                alert('Failed to subscribe.');

            }, 
            complete: function() {   } 
       });       
        return false;
             });
                  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your controller action should return a `PartialViewResult` otherwise it will return your layout page in the response. If you want to cater for both scenarios you can check whether the request is an AJAX request:

```
public ActionResult DeleteItem(int id) {
    // delete your item

    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest()) {
        // return just the partial view
        return PartialView("yourview");
    }


    // otherwise handle normally
    return RedirectToAction("list");
}
```

To understand the difference between returning `View` and returning `PartialView` please see [What's the difference between "return View()" and "return PartialView()"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662285/whats-the-difference-between-return-view-and-return-partialview).

Comment: Thanx for ur answer ,But the view i wanted to return isn't partail so...,I am posting my solution which I got