# Ajax post not working MVC 5

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to post data into a controller but it doesn't seems to work, I need the post to include the content of the view into a div when done but I cant quite achieve it

Here's my js function:

```
function show(num) {
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "html",
        type: "POST",
        url: "Student/Schedule",
        data: { number: num },
        success: function (a) {
            // Replace the div's content with the page method's return.
            alert("success");
            $('#schedule').load(a);
        }
    });
}
```

And, here's my controller:

```
public ActionResult Schedule(String number)
{
    return View(number);
}
```

I am a noob in MVC and C#, so any help is welcome.

Comment: have you decorated your action with `[HttpPost]`?

Comment: What results are  you getting? Are you getting an error?

Comment: no errors, done function doesnt even fire

Comment: what response does the http call get?

Comment: decorated my actions? tell me more

Comment: First confirm that your URL is hitting your controller's action.

Comment: Change Url to "/Student/Schedule".

Comment: @IsaacKleinman it is

Comment: @TZHX i do get schedule view, sorry if i got that wrong i dont think i understand your question

Comment: @BrunoDávilaAssad Did you try `$('#schedule').html(a);` ?

Comment: You need `[HttpPost]` on your action

Comment: Another thing that you shoud pay attention to: You should return PartialView("Schedule", number);. When you use `return View(number)` it uses the string value of number as your view name.You should explicitly pass view name and model

Comment: @BrunoDávilaAssad Did the problem get solve? :)

Comment: @RezaAghaei Yeap, but i used a completly diferent thing called '@Ajax.Actionlink', it worked like a charm, thanks anyways!

Comment: :) happy to hear that you made it work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are somethings that you should fix to solve the problem.

- Change Url to `"/Student/Schedule"`

  You are using `"Student/Schedule"` as url, so you are trying to call an action named "Student".
- Add `[HttpPost]` to your action.
- You should `return PartialView("Schedule", number);`.

  When you use `return View(number)` it uses the string value of number as your view name. You should explicitly pass view name and model.
- Use  `$('#schedule').html(a);`

It's better to add an error function to your ajax call to be able to find errors:

```
error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
    alert(errorThrown); 
    //or you can put jqXHR.responseText somewhere as complete response. Its html.
}
```

Comment: To the down voter, Consider a comment about the reason of down vote.

Comment: Not the downvoter here, but OP says he's getting the view back from the server, so apparently he's hitting the desired action.

Comment: Not downvoter either, true, i am getting my view back, ill destroy that downvote

Comment: I did the downvote for two reasons: 1- The OP said the ajax call is hitting the action, so this answer is irrelevant. 2- I agree that he should change the url, but he should use `Url.Action` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @ataravati :) May be you can offer a better answer, But IMO these are not enough to say an answer is not helpful. The url is obviously wrong and its should be corrected.

Comment: @ataravati Good job :) I prefer to post my answer instead of downvoting other answers. It's better to only downvote totally misleading answers.

Comment: I removed the down-vote. But, your answer is still wrong. :) The most important thing that he needs to change is to return PartialView instead of View.

Comment: Thank you @ataravati, but you should know the only difference between return `View` and return a partial view is in using layout (master page). And returning a view is not the problem itself, return view("something") is the problem, because it tries to return a view with name "something" while the OP needs to pass "something" as model to the view.

Comment: @RezaAghaei, no, that's not true. If he returns a View on an ajax call, it won't work. Period.

Comment: @ataravati Totally wrong! It definitely return view and there is no problem.

Comment: It's very strange and annoying that you downvote answers based on incorrect information. Please search "return view vs return partialview" and for example see [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662285/whats-the-difference-between-return-view-and-return-partialview) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210138/view-vs-partialview)

Answer (score 1):

Your action should return a Partial View, not a View.

Change your action to:

```
[HttpPost]
// by the way use string instead of String
public ActionResult Schedule(string number) 
{
    return PartialView("_Schedule", number);
}
```

Then, you'll need to create a partial view named `_Schedule.cshtml`.

Also, you need to change `$('#schedule').load(a);` to `$('#schedule').html(a);` And, I'd suggest that you use a `Url.Action` to set your url in your ajax call, like this:

```
function show(num) {
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "html",
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("Schedule", "Student")',
        data: { number: num },
        success: function (a) {
            // Replace the div's content with the page method's return.
            alert("success");
            $('#schedule').html(a);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue what i did was adding jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js to my scripts